# Is boto3 client thread-safe

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto3

Is boto3 low level client for S3 thread-safe? Documentation is not explicit about it.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#client

A similar issue is discussed in Github

https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1246

But still there is no answer from maintainers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is boto library thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523680/is-boto-library-thread-safe)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question mentioned above. It is about boto3 not boto.

Answer (score 31):

If you take a look at the [Multithreading/Processing](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-and-multiprocessing) documentation for boto3 you can see that they recommend one client per session as there is shared data between instance that can be mutated by individual threads.

It also looks like there's an open GitHub issue for this exact question. https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1246

Comment: Unfortunatelly the [Multithreading/Processing](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-multiprocessing) states about Resource instance. Nothing is said explicitly about Session or low level Client.

Comment: The example in the doc uses session, though. It seems to me that the recommendation is quite clear that you should use a different session per thread.

Comment: Thanks for the references.  The original issue has been closed, and I've written a condensed answer with links, which validates what you've said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70963911

Answer (score 23):

From [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-multiprocessing):

> Low-level clients are thread safe. When using a low-level client, it is recommended to instantiate your client then pass that client object to each of your threads.

Instantiation of the client is not thread safe while an instance is. To make things work in a multi-threaded environment, put instantiation in a global Lock like this:

```
boto3_client_lock = threading.Lock()

def create_client():
    with boto3_client_lock:
        return boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id='your key id', aws_secret_access_key='your access key')
```

Comment: Correct link https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html. From documentation: Unlike Resources and Sessions, clients are generally thread-safe. There are some caveats, defined below, to be aware of though.

Comment: This is actually the correct solution, the other ones simply put don't work (they always fail with 'credential_provider' and/or 'endpoint_resolver'). It's really needed to lock the client before passing it down to the threaded task runners.

Comment: I guess one has to use the same lock for every place where you implicitly use the default session, like in the above example. For example, if you have both a dynamodb and a s3 client you need to use the same lock when creating both?

Answer (score 14):

I recently tried using the single boto client instance using  `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`. I run into exceptions coming from boto. I assume the boto client is not thread safe in this case.

The exception I got

```
  File "xxx/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 263, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "xxx/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 827, in create_client
    endpoint_resolver = self._get_internal_component('endpoint_resolver')
  File "xxx/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 694, in _get_internal_component
    return self._internal_components.get_component(name)
  File "xxx/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/session.py", line 906, in get_component
    del self._deferred[name]
```

Comment: same, missing the actual exception :)

`KeyError: 'credential_provider'`

Comment: Bizarrely, I get this credential_provider exception when I initialize a boto3 client inside the function that is threaded, but when they all use the same client initialied globally it works

Comment: @LobsterMan Yeah but which way was the wind blowing at that moment?

Comment: The stacktrace shows the exception from `session.py` which is NOT thread safe (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html). You need to distinguish between a `Session` and a `Client`. The latter is thread safe, see code example how to implement it properly https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html

Answer (score 4):

This was answered by the boto team on [May 19, 2021](https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1246#issuecomment-844329486).  See source docs [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html?highlight=multithreading#multithreading-or-multiprocessing-with-resources).

> Resource instances are not thread safe and should not be shared across threads or processes. These special classes contain additional meta data that cannot be shared. It's recommended to create a new Resource for each thread or process:

```
import boto3
import boto3.session
import threading

class MyTask(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        # Here we create a new session per thread
        session = boto3.session.Session()

        # Next, we create a resource client using our thread's session object
        s3 = session.resource('s3')

        # Put your thread-safe code here
```

> In the example above, each thread would have its own Boto3 session and its own instance of the S3 resource. This is a good idea because resources contain shared data when loaded and calling actions, accessing properties, or manually loading or reloading the resource can modify this data.

Comment: So... creating a Session is thread safe? Unlike creating multiple Clients from a single session. And each session creating its own Client is safe?

Answer (score 1):

You can successfully create multiple threads, but you have to instantiate a new session per thread/process and thereby can asynchronously download from an S3 bucket for example.

An example below:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import boto3
import json


files = ["path-to-file.json", "path-to-file2.json"] 

def download_from_s3(file_path):
    # setup a new session
    sess = boto3.session.Session()
    client = sess.client("s3")
    # download a file
    obj = client.get_object(Bucket="<your-bucket>", Key=file_path)
    resp = json.loads(obj["Body"].read())
    return resp

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
     executor.map(download_from_s3, files)
```

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/session.html Session objects are not thread safe and should not be shared across threads and processes. You should create a new Session object for each thread or process.

Comment: You saved my life! I used this and I succeeded to increase the process 80 times!