# Dash app in Docker container not connecting to Dockerised LocalStack implementation

Tags: docker, boto3, plotly-dash, localstack

I am setting up a local instance of a plotly Dash app, which does work when run as a Lambda on AWS.

I am replicating AWS using LocalStack, run in a Docker container - this works fine and can be addressed as expected from the host machine.

I have also containerised the plotly Dash app, which serves the UI for the app. This also works in isolation, but does not connect to the LocalStack container.

I have followed the LocalStack guidance on how to connect containers together, but to no avail.

I've used the standard LocalStack docker implementation, and am starting it with the following command:
`LocalStack start --network ls`

Inspecting it then shows its IP address on the network is 172.19.0.2.

I then start the UI image with the following command (removing names and replacing with <>), as per the LocalStack guidance:
`docker run -it -p 8050:8050 --dns 172.19.0.2 --network ls --name <name> <image>`.

Doing a Docker Network inspect reveals that both containers are on the same network, with IP addresses 172.19.0.2 and 3 respectively.

I then run the dash app in the UI container, which as part of it should call LocalStack to read some DynamoDB tables - it fails to do this, giving me errors along the lines of "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_simulation_author'".

My Docker file for the UI Dash app is (with various bits redacted):

```
FROM XX.dkr.ecr.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/<existing container>

# Install conda dependencies
RUN micromamba install --name base --yes --channel conda-forge \ 
    ffmpeg==5.1.0 \
    imageio \
    imageio-ffmpeg \
    numba \
    dash-leaflet==0.1.23\
    dash-extensions \
    python-kaleido \
    && micromamba clean --force-pkgs-dirs --all --yes

# Additional pip dependencies
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
RUN /opt/conda/bin/python -c "import boto3; s3 = boto3.client('s3'); s3.download_file('<existing files>', '<existing files>', '<existing files>')" \
    && /opt/conda/bin/pip install  \
    <existing files>\
    geo-rasterize==0.8.0  \
    svgpath2mpl \
    pdfkit

# Environment variables, hardcoded
ENV <Batch Env variable> =arn:aws:batch:eu-west-2:000000000000:job-definition/xxx
ENV <Batch Env variable> =arn:aws:batch:eu-west-2:000000000000:job-queue/xxx
ENV <DDB Env variable> = xxx
ENV <S3 Env variable> = xxx
ENV COGNITO_DOMAIN= xxx.auth.eu-west-2.dumydummydummy.com
ENV COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID=eu-west-2_aaaaaaaaa
ENV FLASK_OIDC_CLIENT_ID=fakeforlocal
ENV FLASK_OIDC_CLIENT_SECRET=fakeforlocal
ENV FLASK_OIDC_ISSUER=fakeforlocal
ENV FLASK_SECRET_KEY=fakeforlocal
ENV STRIP_STAGE_PATH=True
ENV LOGIN_DISABLED=True
ENV AWS_ENDPOINT_URL="http://localstack-main:4566"

USER root
RUN apt-get -y update \
    && apt-get install -y wkhtmltopdf \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER $MAMBA_USER

COPY foo/ /opt/projects/foo/

ENV PYTHONPATH "/opt/foo:/opt/projects"

ENTRYPOINT [ "_entrypoint.sh", "/bin/bash" ]
```

I then manually change working directory into /opt/projects and run the index page as a python module:
`python -m foo.bar.dashboard.index`
Which enables me to connect to the dashboard on localhost:8050.

I have tried changing the AWS_ENDPOINT_URL to:
http://localhost:4566
http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566

Neither of which worked either.

May I ask if anyone has any experience / good ideas as to why the UI isn't speaking to LocalStack between containers on the same Docker network?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes up against this in the future (to prevent DenverCoder9  horrors), I solved my problem but think I have found the root of the problem.

1. I solved my problem by running my python app on my host machine directly - this worked for my particular use case, but will be a pain in the future when sharing it because it won't be containerised.
2. I got my ARGs and ENVs confused - the ARGs are just the creds for buildtime, not runtime. Add some ENV creds (they can be fake for localstack) to the dockerfile too.
3. From reading around on the internet, it would appear the problem is a threading issue with boto3 clients or sessions - lots of literature points to different sessions/clients in different python modules not behaving as expected. I didn't have time to resolve this threading issue in my container, but if I did have time that is where I would look next. Look at this sort of question to start your search, and good luck! [Is boto3 client thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52820971/is-boto3-client-thread-safe)